# Adding tabs dynamically in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to add a plus button next to a tab and on click of which I want to add one more tab. Here is my code(see the mentioned plunker).

Currently it does not seem working. Can you please let me know how to add a tab dynamically on click of a button in angular 2.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <tabs>
      <tab [tabTitle]="'Tab 1'">Tab 1 Content</tab>
    </tabs>
  `
})
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/O5EZaw5Nn36QP3XEJM0R?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/O5EZaw5Nn36QP3XEJM0R?p=preview. Sorry the plunker was missed.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 ?

Comment: Yes, the plunker does not seem working correct in this example.

Comment: In the plunker, nothing happens on click of a component. No tab has been added,